# Download a file in VB.net

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-3.5

I'm using the following code to allow users to download a file.

```
Dim myFile As FileInfo = New FileInfo(strPath & strFile)
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & _
Replace(myFile.Name, ".resources", ""))
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", myFile.Length.ToString())
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
Response.WriteFile(myFile.FullName)
```

This method has the annoying problem that any code after this line does not execute correctly.

It pretty ancient code, so I'm guessing there are probably better ways to do this these days. Can anyone suggest one?

Comment: Make sure you clean your response.

Comment: Why have I been marked down here. It seems a pretty clearly-expressed and fair question to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `Response.WriteFile` terminates the response when it's done, so I would imagine you get a `ThreadAbortException`. If you want to write the file to response and continue executing code, I recommend using one of the following 2 options:

1. Change from `WriteFile` to `BinaryWrite`. Use a StreamReader to get the contents of the file into a byte array, and use `BinaryWrite` to write that data to the response. This will not end the response and you can proceed with other code.
2. Postpone the `WriteFile` until after the other "waiting" code is executed. Then return to that line of code to complete the transaction.

Comment: +1: Definitely better than my complete failure to read the code properly on first pass :)

Comment: Thanks. FYI I'm not actually getting any error. The code after writefile just doesn't seem to take effect. I'll try this new method.

Comment: I can't get (1) to work. It just seems to write to the page, rather than giving a download popup. It seems applying (2) doesn't make a difference. If I write lbl.text="hi" before or after writeFile, it still does not take effect.

Comment: Oh, ok, I see your problem. In this case you have a fundamental misunderstanding of the Response itself. You can't perform both actions at the same time. There is one request and one response per page. If you set the response to download a file, that is all you can do. You can't subsequently modify a page afterward from the same response. You may have seen behavior on the web that mimicked this sort of action, but those methods are using multiple request/response actions (usually with AJAX) to achieve the result. In this case you can either download the file or change the label, but not both.

Comment: @Joel: Thanks for identifying the problem. I felt like I was missing something obvious. Seems I was.